# WCF web service stops responding after several repeated calls

Tags: wcf, iis

I have Windows applications that communicate to the logic layer and data layer with a WCF web service.
When the form is opened the connection to the web service is established and the connection is kept alive as long as the form is opened. On closing the from, the connection is closed using Finalize and Dispose on the web service.
After several times opening and closing forms, the service stops responding and I need to reset service which hosted in the IIS to get it working again. Any hints on how to proceed with this issue?

this is my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommandInvoker : IDisposable
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    void Initialize(TypeInfo managerType, UserInfo userInfo, Dictionary<string,string> settingDic);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Finalize();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Action="*")]
    //[CustomOperationBehavior]
    ServerResult Execute(ServerCommand command);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Name="Execute Serialized")]
    string Execute(string command, TypeInfo typeInfo);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Name = "Execute 2 Non Serialized")]
    ServerResult Execute(TypeInfo mangerType, UserInfo userInfo, ServerCommand command);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Name = "Execute 2 Serialized")]
    string Execute(TypeInfo mangerType, UserInfo userInfo, string command, TypeInfo typeInfo);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void BeginExecute(ServerCommand command);
```

and this is my Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class BudgetService : BaseCommandInvoker<BudgetDataContext>, IBudgetService
{
    public BudgetService()
    {
    }
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IBudgetService : ICommandInvoker
{
}
```

Do you have any sample program for this method of use Wcf?

thank you

Comment: my service is decorated with InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession

Comment: The question is...? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you use `manual proxy` for your service?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? Is it IIS Express? Are you running on Windows Server 2003/2008/.../7?

Comment: my iis version is 7. i run my program in windows 7 and 2003 and 2008 and Xp, but in allover problem exist

Answer (score 0):

Could be lots of things!

Is the server returning a timeout? How are you managing your try catch blocks? Are any errors being thrown. I would check if the channel has faulted because an Exception will fault the channel. Your service should be throwing FaultExceptions if something goes wrong.

Impossible to really help ant more without more information.

Comment: thank maddom. after not responding service finally server return timeOut. what is your purpose for managing your try catch blocks? my service work well if i dont't repeat opening and closing forms so in channel not problem.

Comment: The purpose I mention try catch blocks is that it's important the order in what you catch when calling a WCF service. Because FaultException<T> inherits from FaultException, it's important to catch the generic one first or else you may not get to error details you need if you use the wrong order. After do CommunicationException and the TimeoutException. This will make sure you don't 'eat' errors that you need. Hope this helps

Comment: If your service is timing out then I would point the finger at the service. Maybe there is some resource contention? I'd need more detail about the service before I could comment more.

Comment: i dont have any plan for managing try catch for handle wcf faultException.

Comment: I would suggest looking into IErrorHandler and implementing a global error handling strategy for your services. This way you can always make sure that the clients get useful messages back from your services. It will help in tracing problems, and will also help you think about what your service is doing, and I'm sure this will help you write code that is right first time more often and reduce these types of problems that become difficult to find and fix.